# File synchronization apps scorecard?

Tags: data-request, security

EFF has recently created a [Secure Messaging Scorecard](https://www.eff.org/secure-messaging-scorecard) effort to gather data about messaging apps:

[image: Secure Messaging Scorecard]

Is there an effort maintaining similar data for [file synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_synchronization) apps?
(eg: Dropbox, SparkleShare, BitTorrent Sync, etc)

The data columns could be the same.
Ideally as JSON.

Comment: Although it's of interest, I feel this request is more about "information" than "data".